# cannot read property 'queue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey i'm trying to test a music bot with node.js and discord.js. I've put it in 2 servers, in the first one it works fine, in the second one it gives me cannot read property 'queue' of undefined and i don't know why.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");  
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");  
const client = new Discord.Client();


const prefix = "..";
var servers = {};

client.on("message", message => {

let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

function isValidURL(string) {
    var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    return (res !== null)
  };

switch(args[0]){
    case "play":

        function play(connection, message){
            var serv = servers[message.guild.id];

            serv.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(serv.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

            serv.queue.shift();

            serv.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                if(serv.queue[0]){
                    play(connection, message);
                }else{
                    connection.disconnect();
                }

            });

        }


        if(!args[1]){
            message.channel.send(message.author.toString() + " Devi mettere un link dopo il comando.");
            return;
        }else if(isValidURL(args[1]) == false){
            message.channel.send(message.author.toString() + " Link non valido.");
            return;
        }else if(!message.member.voice.channel){
            message.channel.send(message.author.toString() + " Devi essere in un canale vocale.");
            return;
        }else if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.channel.id] = {
            queue: []
        }

        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if(!message.member.voice.connection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
            play(connection, message);
        });




    break;

}





 });

 client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

It might be something with servers permissions but they are the same. So i don't know, any idea?

Comment: Does `var servers = {};` have any properties or is it an empty object?

Comment: I've solved the matter, i selected a wrong parameter of an object instead of the correct one, now it works, thanks anyway!

Comment: Great, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

The discord.js library may be updated to a new master version which the bot is not compatible with. Try using the version of discord.js which is used in the original source.

Comment: If it is it then, why it works in my personal discord server and not in my friend's?

Comment: In the end i solved the probelm, it was a wrong parameter i used instead of another, thanks anywyay!